# Jquery mobile strange behaviour

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to retrieve text in collapsible header which is the previous sibling of a 'p' tag. Its quite trivial code, but it doesn't work with jquery mobile enabled.

`I made a fiddle to better explain:`
    http://jsfiddle.net/gypwtqq9/

Disable the jquery mobile extension in the fiddle and see it working just fine. How can I get around this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve count in collapsible header?

Comment: yes, I will update with that info. Any toughts on how to get this value?

Comment: Use `.closest(".ui-collapsible").find(".ui-li-count").text()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to get there, but this will work:

```
var val = $(this).parents(".ui-collapsible").find('.ui-li-count').text();
```

The jQM adds a container div around the body p element, so fid the parent div that is the ui-collapsible and then find the ui-li-count span within the collapsible.

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/gypwtqq9/2/)**